# Django form wizard and django-paypal

Tags: django, django-forms, django-paypal

I am trying to put a paypal form inside a form wizard. The fields are being displayed, but the button is not showing up for some reason.

I wrapped the form wizard inside a view, and it is working. The only thing that is missing is the paypal button.

views.py

```
def add(request):
    paypal_dict = {
        "cmd": "_xclick-subscriptions",
        "business": "alexbrand09@gmail.com",
        "p3": 1,                           # duration of each unit (depends on unit)
        "t3": "M",                         # duration unit ("M for Month")
        "src": "1",                        # make payments recur
        "sra": "1",                        # reattempt payment on payment error
        "no_note": "1",                    # remove extra notes (optional)
        "notify_url": "http://www.example.com/your-ipn-location/",
        "return_url": "http://www.example.com/your-return-location/",
        "cancel_return": "http://www.example.com/your-cancel-location/",
        "custom": request.user.id
    }

    silver_payment = {
        "a3": "15",
        "item_name": "Silver Business Profile",
    }

    platinum_payment = {
        "a3": "25",
        "item_name": "Platinum Business Profile",
    }

    # add other keys from paypal_dict
    silver_payment.update(paypal_dict)
    platinum_payment.update(paypal_dict)

    initial = {
        '3':silver_payment,
        '4':platinum_payment,
    }

    #create form wizard
    form = AddWizard.as_view([AddForm1, AddForm2, AddForm3, PayPalPaymentsForm,PayPalPaymentsForm],
            initial_dict = initial,
            condition_dict = {
                '1': basic_ad_selected,
                '2': silver_ad_selected,
                '3': silver_ad_selected,
                '4': platinum_ad_selected
            })

    return form(context=RequestContext(request), request=request)
```

template:

```
{% block content %}

{% load bootstrap %}

<h2>Payment Information</h2>

CARD FORM

<form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}

{{ wizard.management_form }}

{% if wizard.form.forms %}
    {{ wizard.form.management_form }}
    {% for form in wizard.form.forms %}
        {{ form|bootstrap }}

    {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {{ wizard.form|bootstrap }}

{% endif %}
<br/><br/>
{% if wizard.steps.prev %}
<button class="btn" name="wizard_goto_step" type="submit" value="{{ wizard.steps.prev }}">&laquo; Go Back</button>
{% endif %}
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" />Next &raquo;</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

I am not sure why all fields of the paypal form would show up but not the button itself

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap tag was getting rid of the button...

The button is now showing up.